# How to use CSVIMPORT to get a row

Tags: matlab

How to use CSVIMPORT function in matlab to access a row of csv file as a 1D vector?

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
  [C1 C2 C3] = CSVIMPORT( fileName, 'columns', {'C1', 'C2', C3'}, ... )
```

read this for parameters you can set in [csvimport](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport)